# FUN.VALUE argument in vapply

Tags: r, list, apply

I don't really get the `FUN.VALUE` argument in `vapply`.
Here is my example:

```
a = list(list(1,2), list(1), list(1,2,3))

# give the lengths of each list in a
sapply(a, length)
```

Now, I try to make it type-safe using `vapply` instead of `sapply`

```
# gives me same result as sapply
vapply(a, length, FUN.VALUE=1)

# same result, but why?
vapply(a, length, FUN.VALUE=1000)

# gives me error
vapply(a, length, FUN.VALUE="integer")

# gives me error
vapply(a, length, FUN.VALUE="vector")

# gives me error
vapply(a, length, FUN.VALUE=c(1,2))
```

From `?vapply` I read that `FUN.VALUE` can be a scalar, vector or matrix, and is used to match the type of the output. Any hints for why `vapply` behaves this way?

Comment: But, length gives a single number.  You can use `vapply(a, length, FUN.VALUE= numeric(1))` or `vapply(a, length, FUN.VALUE= integer(1))`  But it will give errors with `vapply(a, length, FUN.VALUE= character(1))`  Here the number inside the bracket denotes the length of expected output from each loop

Comment: Regarding using a single numeric value for `FUN.VALUE` i think it is parsing it as numeric instead of the length. i.e. you can pass any number `vapply(a, length, FUN.VALUE= 0)` to get the same output.  But, if you pass it as  string, it senses `character` output `vapply(a, length, FUN.VALUE= "0")` and gives error

Comment: For `vapply`, you need to define the type (integer, character, logical) AND length in parentheses as @akrun shows if coercible. But passing a single number is interesting that it worked. I wonder if that holds true for other methods like matrix/array returns. Off to the lab!

Comment: Ok, git it I think, type and length returned from function is asked; thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `vapply` documentation,

> `FUN.VALUE` (generalized) vector; a template for the return value from FUN. See ‘Details’.

Notice that it says "a template for the return value", not "a character string describing the return value". Looking in the *Details* section provides more guidance:

> This function checks that all values of `FUN` are compatible with the `FUN.VALUE`, **in that they must have the same length and type.** [Emphasis added]

The function in your example, `length()` returns a numeric of length 1, (an integer, if we want to be specific). When you use `FUN.VALUE = 1`, `1` has the same length and type as the output you expect, so the check passes. When you use `FUN.VALUE = "integer"`, `"integer"` is a character vector of length 1, so the length check passes but the type check fails.

It continues:

> (Types may be promoted to a higher type within the ordering logical < integer < double < complex, but not demoted.)

So, if you were `vapply`ing a function that might return a value that is integer or double, you should make sure to specify something like `FUN.VALUE = 1.0`

The documentation continues to talk about how arrays/matrices are handled. I won't copy/paste it here.

Comment: how about vapply to a character string containing dataframe names of a bunch of datasets that I have in my R environment. I would like to use the get function. What would FUN.VALUE default to in that case?

Comment: If your function returns data frames, "same length and type" would suggest a `list` (data frames are special lists), with the length of the number of columns in your result. If they have different numbers of columns `vapply` won't work. And even then, `vapply`  probably won't get you much here. Perhaps just use `mget`?